# Why does wineprefixcreate create an empty directory?

Tags: wine, games

I used this short guide to attempt making a separate wine prefix in my home folder:
[How to Use WinePrefix in Ubuntu to Optimize Gaming](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Administration/How-to-Use-WinePrefix-in-Ubuntu-to-Optimize-Gaming/)

Seems pretty simple but isn't working for me. The `mkdir` works and puts a new folder in my `/home` folder. But when I use that folder name in `wineprefixcreate` it doesn't show up with the c: drive and such in that folder like my `.wine/` folder.

Is there a codec or something that I'm missing? Could I just copy and paste the files from .wine into that new folder?

I'm trying my hardest not to give up on Ubuntu but I've had this almost 2 weeks now and haven't been able to get a single game to work yet. Would really like to play Neverwinter MMO, KoToR, LoL, etc. Please help and thank you. I have Wine 1.4 and Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Comment: Make sure you assign the `WINEPREFIX` variable at the command line in front of the `wineprefixcreate` command. E.g.: `WINEPREFIX="/home/zach/my-game" wineprefixcreate`

Comment: I did... E.g. :mkdir Neverwinter           then:WINEPREFIX="/home/zach/Neverwinter"wineprefixcreate

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have a space between the closing quote and the `wineprefixcreate` command? E.g.: `WINEPREFIX="/home/zach/Neverwinter" wineprefixcreate`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wine Wiki](http://wine-wiki.org/index.php/Wineprefixcreate), `wineprefixcreate` is now deprecated and there is no need to run it anymore.

> Just run wine and everything happens automatically. It was for [a]
>   manual update of a WINE prefix. Now it is automatic and therefore it
>   isn't needed anymore.

Also take a look at the screenshot in the article linked in the Question:

[image: wineprefixcreate output]

It also displays a Notice:

- `wineprefixcreate` is deprecated and shouldn't be needed anymore.
- `WINEPREFIX` creation and updates now happen automatically when needed.

Thus all you should do is to set the `WINEPREFIX` variable and run your game with wine.

You should run something similar:

```
WINEPREFIX="/home/zach/Neverwinter" wine /path/to/your-neverwinter-setup.exe
```

Just to make sure I've just run a test case:

```
WINEPREFIX="/home/user/WINETEST" wine regedit.exe
```

A window opened stating the wine environment is getting refreshed and then the registry editor started up.

**NOTE**
As [soulsource](https://askubuntu.com/users/17056/soulsource) has pointed out, the *prefix directory should not be created beforehand*. It can cause issues when it already exists. Just run wine with the appropriate prefix set and it will be created properly. As the comment states:

> Small sidenote: If you want to create a new WINEPREFIX, do not create
>   the directory beforehand. Wine will create it on the first run with
>   the appropriate WINEPREFIX automatically. If the directory already
>   exists, numerous issues can arise, the most prominent is that the
>   WINEARCH setting is ignored. "Note: During prefix creation, the 64-bit
>   version of wine treats all folders as 64-bit prefixes and will not
>   create a 32-bit in any existing folder. To create a 32-bit prefix you
>   have to let wine create the folder specified in WINEPREFIX." 
>   Source: [ArchWiki - Using WINEARCH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wine#Using_WINEARCH)

Comment: Small sidenote: If you want to create a new WINEPREFIX, do not create the directory beforehand. Wine will create it on the first run with the appropriate WINEPREFIX automatically. If the directory already exists, numerous issues can arise, the most prominent is that the WINEARCH setting is ignored. "Note: During prefix creation, the 64-bit version of wine treats all folders as 64-bit prefixes and will not create a 32-bit in any existing folder. To create a 32-bit prefix you have to let wine create the folder specified in WINEPREFIX." - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wine#Using_WINEARCH

Comment: @soulsource Thanks for the heads up! I've included your comment into the answer and edited accordingly.